# Where query from other table + Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm stuck with creating a where query.
 I have table `item` with `item_id, item_title, item_description, item_created, item_approved`. I also have a table `article` with PK `item_id` (from item table) and `article_body`. The last table is `media` with `medium_id`, `item_id` (FK), `medium_url` and `medium_type`.

Now I would like to select all the data from media where item.item_approved is not NULL and where item.item_id ins't present in the article table.
Now I can select all the data from media where item.item_approved is not NULL. But now I need to do another check that he doesn't select the items that are also in article table. My query so far:

```
$repository = $entityManager->getRepository('VolleyScoutBundle:Media');

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('m')
    ->join('m.item', 'i')
    ->where('i.itemApproved is not NULL')
    ->getQuery();
```

Comment: Does `item_approved` is nullable in DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely that you must use 2 queries. With JOINs it can not be done.